# How to convert node js project in SDK and use/consume that SDK in another node js project?

Tags: node.js

I have an existing node js project which is used to make some API calls and log the responses (Basically to get Auth headers).

I want to convert the above project in to SDK and use the same SDK in another node project to make few other API calls using Auth headers (responses) from SDK.

I am completely new to Node js. So, was thinking from C# perspective. I know how to do that in C#/.net but not sure of node Js. Any guidance or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is not related to C# and .NET in general, I have removed these tags. In Node.JS you can just reuse file by importing, just like you would reuse class in C#. If you want to make it publicly available as external dependency, then you may want to create a Node.JS package (just like NuGet package) - there is plenty information in the Intenet on it as well.

Comment: As the Op is new to the language you shouldn't downvote. Lead him to the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no word like `SDK` in `NodeJS`. Instead we have `packages`. You can create your own package and publish it or keep it for reusing.

[Reference One](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules)

[Reference Two](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/how-to-build-and-publish-a-npm-package)

Comment: Gotcha. So, nugetPackage/sdk is similar to npm packages. Thank you for the info.  Now I can head in the right direction. I will bug you if I have any questions or stuck somewhere while creating package. :-)